# How to allow spanish accent markers to display correctly in visualforce

Tags: visualforce, language

I want to display some spanish accent markers in visualforce page.
I used this simple line:

```
<apex:outputText  value="Test Spanish Accent Markers : límite"/>
```

but it is rendering as

[image]

Please advise the correct method. One method i know is using HTML codes as mentioned [here](http://symbolcodes.tlt.psu.edu/bylanguage/spanish.html)
But i don't want to use this as i have to use multiple markers.

Comment: Just tested on my dev org and it works well, without that strange sign. I think you need to check your browser encoding (I have Unicode UTF-8).

Comment: @mast0r I checked and Encoding is Unicode UTF-8 in my google chrome. but still having this issue. Chrome version 37.0.2062.120

Comment: Also tried using <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> in VF page, but still same issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`, but **ALSO** you need to actually encode your page as utf-8 when you save it.

Here is how you do it in SublimeText - Select your file and from the File Menu choose "Save with Encoding"
[image: Save with Encoding]

To do it with Eclipse, Right-click on the file, choose Properties and ensure that UTF-8 is selected.
[image: Image showing Encoding is UTF-8]